# Run GUI application via OpenSSH on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, openssh

I would like to launch a GUI application on a Windows 10 Desktop machine via the built-in OpenSSH server.
The issue is that it doesn't seem to render the GUI in the correct user session?

The application shows up in the task manager but does not render.
I found some (ugly) workarounds that supposedly work on Windows 7 and 8 but not really something that works on Windows 10. Preferably this shouldn't involve changing how I launch the application but changing how the SSH server is launching programs.

I'm logged in via ssh as the user who is also logged into a Desktop session on the actual machine.
On Linux you would have to specify which X11 sessions the app should launch in via an environment variable (e.g. DISPLAY=:0). Do I have to do something similar on windows to tell the shell in which context to launch the application?

Comment: If you are logged onto a computer remotely you may not affect the physical user. Your program will be invisible. Otherwise the physical user would not have control of their machine.

Comment: Any way to circumvent that? Given that I have full ownership of the machine and can set it up however I want?
On Linux this is absolutely no problem :/

Comment: It a security thing. You may not mount denial of service to a physical user. So Windows is designed to PREVENT it. Linux isn't as designed. Having said that https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec emulates the physical user.

Comment: Also PsExec is from a company MS bought and goes through contortions to do what it does. It copies files using hidden administrators shares, installs a service, that starts a program as the physical user.. The Windows way is to use Remote Help. You can take over the physical user's desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem easy to circumvent
Let's [invent yet another wheel](https://github.com/Un1Gfn-nt/ntexec)

Server side

- Listen on a UDP port
- Call [`ShellExecute(NULL,"open",...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch) on received packets
- Able to open URLs in the default browser or launch GUI applications e.g. cmd/Taskmgr/mmc, which just pops up on the screen, all Linux_Xorg_SSH_DISPLAY=:0'ish
- <del>"It works on my machine."</del> Works on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.746]
- **No authentication implemented**
- **Does not check what is in the UDP packet or if it is valid for ShellExecute()**

Client side

- Send a UDP packet for the server to execute
- Save IP address of the server, provided in argv, so that you may omit it the next time

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows OpenSSH service is not running you can start it from the intended user.  A startup script is fine for that.

Create the user SSH keys in Windows (you usually do this anyways):

```
 ssh-keygen
```

Accept the default location.
I tested it with no pass-phrase.

Start OpenSSH, using the user's private key as host key:

```
start /min %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\sshd -h %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\id_rsa
```

You could create a one-line sshd.bat with the above, and link to it from shell:startup.